# How to speed up convolution for symmetrical property of a half-band FIR filter?

Tags: convolution, finite-impulse-response, symmetry

I've discovered that such convolution can be further sped because of symmetric coefficients but I'm not able to get it right.

The filter is a low pass filter at 11025Hz for 44100Hz, with 461 taps.

The convolution that skips half the taps, that works:

```
public float ProcessHalf(float input)
{
    var length = H.Length;
    var center = H.Length / 2;

    Z[State] = Z[State + length] = input;

    var output = 0.0f;

    for (var i = 1; i < length; i += 2)
    {
        output += H[i] * Z[State + length - i];
    }

    output += H[center] * Z[State + length - center];

    State--;

    if (State < 0)
    {
        State += length;
    }

    return output;
}
```

The convolution that attempts to further half iterations, does not work:

```
public float ProcessQuarter(float input)
{
    var length = H.Length;
    var center = H.Length / 2;

    Z[State] = Z[State + length] = input;

    var output = 0.0f;

    for (var i = 1; i < center; i += 2)
    {
        var j = State + length - i;
        var k = State + length + i - center; // this is not right

        var a = Z[j];
        var b = Z[k];

        output += H[i] * (a + b);
    }

    output += H[center] * Z[State + length - center];

    State--;

    if (State < 0)
    {
        State += length;
    }

    return output;
}
```

When I check the result, not only it's not filtered, but its volume is lower.

Can you tell where the problem is in the algorithm?

Comment: With 461 taps, and assuming that H.length =461, what do you expect `var center` to be? Besides that, you could try to take a smaller example like a filter with 11 taps and write down with a pen what the indexes of a symmetric filter should be and compare this with what you calculate for `j` and `k`. This will help you to debug your own code

Comment: Thanks for pointing that one out as well, I've added an answer explaining how to deal with both :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [**@Irreducible**](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/30571/irreducible) tips, here's the answer on what the problem was but also on why `center` may be a problem in some cases.

The right offset to subtract from state is `(center + (center - t))`:

```
public float ProcessQuarter(float input)
{
    var length = H.Length;
    var center = length / 2;
    var offset = State + length;

    Z[State] = Z[offset] = input;

    var output = 0.0f;

    for (var t = 1; t < center; t += 2)
    {
        var l = offset - t;
        var r = offset - (center + (center - t));

        var a = Z[l];
        var b = Z[r];

        output += H[t] * (a + b);
    }

    output += H[center] * Z[offset - center];

    State--;

    if (State < 0)
    {
        State += length;
    }

    return output;
}
```

Now the center may be a problem depending it's odd or even, this little test shows how it either gets skipped or included when processing half of the taps:

```
var list = new[] { 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 459, 461, 463 };

foreach (var taps in list)
{
    var center = taps / 2;
    var mirror = center % 2 == 0;

    Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(taps)}: {taps}, {nameof(center)}: {center}, {nameof(mirror)}: {mirror}");

    Console.WriteLine("\titerating 1 in 2 taps NOPE:");

    for (var i = 1; i < taps; i += 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\t\t{(i == center ? "\tcenter " : "")}{i}");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\titerating 1 in 4 taps GOOD:");

    for (var i = 1; i < center; i += 2)
    {
        var j = i;
        var k = center + (center - i);
        Console.WriteLine($"\t\t{j} {k}");

        Assert.AreEqual(taps, j + k + 1);
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"\t\tTODO convolve center: {center}");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

For 11 taps:

```
taps: 11, center: 5, mirror: False
iterating 1 in 2 taps NOPE:
    1
    3
        center 5
    7
    9
iterating 1 in 4 taps GOOD:
    1 9
    3 7
    TODO convolve center: 5
```

For 13 taps:

```
taps: 13, center: 6, mirror: True
    iterating 1 in 2 taps NOPE:
        1
        3
        5
        7
        9
        11
    iterating 1 in 4 taps GOOD:
        1 11
        3 9
        5 7
        TODO convolve center: 6
```

For 15 taps:

```
taps: 15, center: 7, mirror: False
    iterating 1 in 2 taps NOPE:
        1
        3
        5
            center 7
        9
        11
        13
    iterating 1 in 4 taps GOOD:
        1 13
        3 11
        5 9
        TODO convolve center: 7
```

For 17 taps:

```
taps: 17, center: 8, mirror: True
    iterating 1 in 2 taps NOPE:
        1
        3
        5
        7
        9
        11
        13
        15
    iterating 1 in 4 taps GOOD:
        1 15
        3 13
        5 11
        7 9
        TODO convolve center: 8
```

Note however that isn't a problem when using symmetry as the loops evaluates `t < center`, i.e. it is never included and must be computed after the loop.

Here's the corrected code for `center` when processing 1 taps in 2:

```
public float ProcessHalf(float input)
{
    var length = H.Length;
    var center = length / 2;
    var offset = State + length;

    Z[State] = Z[offset] = input;

    var output = 0.0f;

    for (var t = 1; t < length; t += 2)
    {
        var l = offset - t;

        output += H[t] * Z[l];
    }

    if ((center & 1) == 0)
    {
        output += H[center] * Z[offset - center];
    }

    State--;

    if (State < 0)
    {
        State += length;
    }

    return output;
}
```